# Return NULL or Empty Values When Data Doesn't Exist

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have a query that returns customer info, billing info, and the stores that she shopped at info.  I'm joining on the Cust_Id which is the key to each table.    All of Jennifer's (Customer) information comes back fine as she has data in each field. I have a situation where Susan (Customer) doesn't return anything because one of her store_names doesn't have a location.  How do I modify this query to show Susan even if here store doesn't have a location?  Therefore it will be a null or empty value.  Thank you in advance..

```
Select Distinct a.first_name, a.last_name, a.customer_No, 
                b.bill_type, b.bill_date, c.store_names, c.store_location

                from Customer a 
                Inner Join Billing b
                On a.Cust_Id = b.Cust_Id
                Inner Join StoreDetail c
                On a.CustId = c.CustId
```

Comment: Change `Inner Join StoreDetail ...` to `Left Join StoreDetail...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called an outer join.  It returns null for tables with out matching values.

```
Select Distinct a.first_name, a.last_name, a.customer_No, 
            b.bill_type, b.bill_date, c.store_names, c.store_location

            from Customer a 
            Inner Join Billing b
            On a.Cust_Id = b.Cust_Id
            Left Join StoreDetail c
            On a.CustId = c.CustId
```